# Why am I importing so many classes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm looking at example Spark code and I'm a bit confused as to why the sample code I'm looking at requires two import statements:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

This is Scala. As I understand it, _ is the wildcard character. So this looks like I'm importing SparkContext twice. Can anybody shed light on this?

Comment: Since Spark 2.2 is out, I'd strongly recommend staying away from the packages unless you do have a reason not to. Use Spark SQL (with `SparkSession` among the other goodies).

Comment: Studying for an exam. You know how it goes.

Comment: this can be shortened to `import org.apache.spark._, SparkContext._`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This first line says to import all of the classes in the package `org.apache.spark`. This means you can use all of those classes without prefixing them with the package name.

The second line says to import all of the static members of the class `SparkContext`. This means you can use those members without prefixing their names with the class name.

Remember `import` doesn't really do anything at run time; it just lets you write less code. You aren't actually "importing" anything twice. The use of the term `import` comes from Java, and admittedly it is confusing.

This might help:

Without the first line, you would have to say

```
org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

but the first import line lets you say

```
SparkContext
```

If you had only the first line and *not* the second, you would have to write

```
SparkContext.getOrCreate
```

but with both import lines you can just write

```
getOrCreate
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!